# TypeError: dataFile.saveDataFile is not a function in angularjs service

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I'm getting the error `TypeError: dataFile.saveDataFile is not a function` when trying to call the function saveDataFile from my dataFile service (funnily enough).

The dataFile service code is below, it's a little more odd because the loadDataFile function gets called and works no problem.

```
angular.module('crmApp').
factory('data', function($http, $filter, $q){

var data = {};
data.data;

// Get the data from the DB
data.getData = function () {
  var d = $q.defer();
  if (data.data) {
    console.log("There's already data");
    d.resolve(data.data);
    // console.log(data.data);
    // return data.data;
  }
  else {
    console.log("there's no data, asking for it");
    return $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: '/getAllData'})
    .then(function(response) {
      data.data = response.data;
      d.resolve(data.data);
      // return data.data;
    },
    function myError(response) {
        console.log(response);
        return 1;
    });
  }
  return d.promise;
}
```

The place I'm calling it from - controller.addTasks is here:

```
'use strict';

angular.
  module('addTask')
    .controller("addTask", ["$scope", "dataFile",
      function($scope, dataFile) {
        $scope.addTask = function(dataFile, group) {
          // create the tasks json
          var newTaskCreated = (new Date).getTime();
          var newTask = { "task" : $scope.newTaskDescription,
                      "created" : newTaskCreated,
                      "group" : group,
                      "today" : false,
                      "status" : "incomplete"};
          $scope.tasks.push(newTask);
          console.log($scope.tasks);

      // Save the new data in tasksData.json
      dataFile.saveDataFile($scope.tasks);

      // add the task to the screen


      // reset the blank addtask input box
      $scope.newTaskDescription = "";

    }

  }]);
```

None of the similar posts I've seen have helped so any help you can offer is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you are using .service (this) not .factory (return object.)

Comment: try var svc = this; note that service uses constructor function. also remove return svc.

Comment: if above works successfully please delete this question it no longer helpful.

Comment: Thanks, I was previously using 'this' instead of 'svc' and not returning svc but a friend suggested changing it (as that's how he did his services) but I still got the same error

Comment: You are injecting `dataFile` into your controller and then within the `addTask` function you have defined a parameter called `dataFile`. Unless you are passing an instance into that function (I imagine it's unlikely), you are setting `dataFile` to null. I would remove the `dataFile` param from the `addTask` function.

Comment: @Corporalis - that fixed it, thanks! Now onto my next error!

Comment: No worries, good luck!